# Install fail: DSX Desktop (IBM_DSX_Desktop - Vs.: 1.2.3 - 3/27/18) on Windows 10

Tags: dsx-desktop

I'm trying to install DSX Desktop (IBM_DSX_Desktop - Vs.: 1.2.3 - 3/27/18)
on Windows 10 and it fails with the following error:

> [2018-04-23 16:29:59:0524] [error] Error while pulling
>   hybridcloudibm/dsx-desktop:rstudio:Error: (HTTP code 500) server error
>   - {"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while
>   awaiting headers)"}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it seems that Docker is unable to access the registry. You can test it by trying `docker pull hello-world`, which should also fail with the same error message.

This can happen if you're behind a proxy. If that's the case, [this article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#proxy-configuration) on how to configure a proxy for docker, may be of use.